# Can I user CAPI 2-factor authentication in MobaXterm?

Tags: mobaxterm, two-factor-authentication

I am needing to do some work on Linux servers that require 2-factor authentication using a PIV card. The instructions I was given are based on `PuTTy-CAC` but I woild like to use `MobaXterm`. I wasn't able to find equivalent settings ("CAPI Certificate") in MobaXterm.

Is there any way to use MobaXterm where 2-factor authentication is required and how?

Answer (score 2):

Load your CAPI keys into [PuTTY-CAC's *Pageant*](https://github.com/NoMoreFood/putty-cac/releases) (SSH signature agent). MobaXterm supports using Pageant for authentication (partly because its SSH client is indeed based on PuTTY). This also works with a few other clients, such as WinSCP or Bitvise Tunnelier.

[image: (Screenshot of Pageant-CAC's key list)]

Comment: That sounds nice but all I'm able to get off my PIV card is the private but not the public key which `Pageant` requires

Comment: Do you mean the opposite? And Pageant doesn't require the private key any more than PuTTY itself doesn't. It requires the _ability to sign_, which the "-CAC" version can obtain via CAPI.

Answer (score 1):

As MobaXterm is compatible with Pageant, you can select the option "Use external Pageant" in SSH option, and use [PIVageant](https://github.com/bitlogik/PIVageant) as the agent. I developed it for my own purpose. It uses the PIV key storage to auth in a server. That would require at most some customization as the current configuration if for 9E pinless slot, and also it is focus on Yubico 5.

Answer (score 0):

yes

In pageant, you copy the  line and use that under
sessions -> User sessions -> New Session-> SSH -> Advanced SSH Settings -> Use Private Key (check) -> paste