# Extracting private key from PIV card

Tags: two-factor-authentication, pageant

I can get the public key out of my PIV card (using `PuTTy`) but I am unable to get the private key, which I would like to emulate the card by running `Pageant`. Is there any way to get the private key out of the card?

**RELATED:** [Can I user CAPI 2-factor authentication in MobaXterm?](https://superuser.com/questions/1329159/can-i-user-capi-2-factor-authentication-in-mobaxterm)

Comment: Short answer, No.....https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92775/malware-extract-private-keys-from-smartcard

Answer (score 2):

No, smartcards *by design* have no method of revealing the private key.

But you **do not need** to extract the private key – SSH authentication only requires the ability to sign (and the whole concept of "key agents" is built on that). Just as PuTTY-CAC can create signatures using your smartcard via CAPI (or PKCS#11), [Pageant-CAC](https://github.com/NoMoreFood/putty-cac/releases) can do exactly the same.

[image: (Screenshot of Pageant-CAC's key list)]

Answer (score 1):

You can't extract the private key out of a PIV smartcard, as this is done as a secure vault for the private key.
But you can use a Putty agent compatible with Pageant which uses a PIV card as a secure key storage, that's the clear goal of [PIVageant](https://github.com/bitlogik/PIVageant), that my company developed. It can work with any SSH/SFTP software that can use Pageant such as Putty, Kitty, WinSCP, X2Go client, Fork, ...